How to fix "broken" repo with bad remote fetchref
If git has a bad fetchref configured for a remote -- "bad" meaning that the ref does not exist on the remote -- the remote becomes "broken" and no operations with it will work.
Here's a nice little testcase
$> git config --local --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/foo/bar:refs/remotes/forks/foo/bar"
$> git fetch
fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/foo/bar
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

I can solve it like this, but it feels very "hacky" and I'm hoping there's a better way.
    # A bad ref here will really mess up git
    remote=${1:-origin}
    for fetchref in $(git fetch "$remote" 2>&1 | grep "find remote ref" | sed -e "s/.*find remote ref//")
    do
        echo "Removing bad ref: $fetchref"
        git config --local --unset "remote.$remote.fetch" "$fetchref"
    done

This is mildly better but it still feels overly-complicated and fragile.
for fetchref in $(git config --get-all "remote.${remote}.fetch"); do
    ref="${fetchref#:*}" # everything after the colon
    [[ "$ref" =~ \*$ ]] && continue
    if ! git ls-remote --exit-code "${remote}" "$ref" &>/dev/null; then
        echo "Bad ref: $fetchref does not exist on ${remote}. Removing."
        git config --local --unset "remote.${remote}.fetch" "$ref"
    fi
done


Does the branch foo/bar exist in the remote repo?

No, it does not. (I'll clarify the question.)

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

FWIW: your second option (reading the configuration, and checking one by one the references) looks solid enough for me. The elements you depend on are pretty core in git and unlikely to change anytime soon.
